# Installation problem

Tags: system-installation

Ihave created a separate partion for Ubuntu and when I use the windows installer  to install Ubuntu into that drive i'm facing an error while extracting kernel that "An error has occurred setting the element data. the request is not supported."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about that but the better option I found was (in my case) to install ubuntu 12.04 as a virtual machine in windows desktop, whereas I preferred to have ubuntu-only on a separate laptop.

Comment: But is it not possible to install 12.10 with windows8 side by side in a different partition??????